# Posting Multiple Input Text Value with Same (input)Name

Tags: php

I am using php to `insert` into [Microsoft SQL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php) table and the below is my code:

```
$server = "**/**,1433";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"***", "UID"=>"**", "PWD"=>"******" );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $server, $connectionInfo );
if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {

$sql = "SELECT Item.HQID, Item.ItemLookupCode, Item.Description, Item.ExtendedDescription, Item.SalePrice, Item.Price, Item.CategoryID FROM Item WHERE Item.HQID = '$check'";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

 $html_table = '<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">';

 $html_table .= '<form method="post" action="upload.php"><tr><td width="350" align ="center">' .$row['Description']. '</td><td width="350" align ="center">' .$row['ExtendedDescription']. '</td><td width="130" align="center">' 

.$row['ItemLookupCode']. '<td width="100" align="center">' .$row['SalePrice']. '</td><td width="100" align="center">' .$row['Price']. '</td><td width="200" align="center"><input 

type="text" size="24" name="stitle"></td><td width="100" align="center"><input type="text" size="8" name="wprice"></td><td width="120" align="center"><input type="text" size="10" name="scategory"></td><td width="220" align="center"><input 

type="text" size="28" name="sbody"></td></tr>';
$html_table .= '</table>'; 
echo $html_table;  
}
}
}
}
?>
<input type="submit" value="Upload this page" ></form>
```

I have an `<input>` with `name="stitle"` and I want the **PHP** code to take values from each `<input>` but currently it picks up the value just from the first `<input>`. How do I fix this?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you reformat your HTML - vertical scroll is horrible (hence why web developers and designers spend an age to avoid it).

Comment: I would also suggest you remove all code from the example that is not required for the question - this extra code begs more questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your post is horrible formatted, but I think you're looking for the array notation.

You can make something like that:

```
<input type="text" size="24" name="stitle[]">
```

The `$_POST` array field `stitle` is an array with all values after submitting the form.

Comment: Also worth noting, you can add keys to those arrays too, and the arrays can be multi-dimensional.

Comment: Max, how did this not work? $_POST['stitle'] should be an array - try print_r($_POST['stitle'])

Comment: Yes SEoF is right..by the way why are you outputting the `$html_table` beyond the html and body tag?

Comment: Don't mind the other part of code, it is just part of code which was deleted while i am posting this question SeoF, can you show me the code which is supposed in "upload.php" thanks....

Comment: See my answer for a basic example.

Comment: I solved the problem it was browser not working with chrome but works with i.e (Localhost, apache server) Thank you guys so much

Answer (score 2):

OK, a simple example of the form, ignoring all extra syntactical mark-up

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
</pre>

<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" size="24" name="stitle[]" />
    <input type="text" size="24" name="stitle[]" />
    <input type="text" size="24" name="stitle[]" />
</form>
```

Now, anything you enter into those three text boxes will all be returned, and be accessible in the "$_POST" variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use the array style inputs [] and you have control over the qty of fields then you can also do the following:

```
for($f=0; $f < 5; $f++){ 

 echo '<input type="text" name="foo_'.$f.'">';

}

/*-----------server-side------------*/

for($f=0; $f < 5; $f++){ 

 if(isset($_POST['foo_'.$f])){
  //do something
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple code for multiple simple input

```
$stitle=$_POST['stitle'];
for($j=0;$j<count($stitle);$j++)
{
    echo   $stitle[$j]."<br>";
}
```